# PaperVision error when using right-to-left based text

Tags: actionscript-3, right-to-left, papervision3d

My code is generating the following error (it is supposed to make a 3D right-to-left text animation with PaperVision):

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

However, this error only appears when I enter `right-to-left` oriented text. When I use English text, I get no error.

Here is my code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    import org.papervision3d.scenes.Scene3D
    import org.papervision3d.view.Viewport3D
    import org.papervision3d.cameras.Camera3D
    import org.papervision3d.render.BasicRenderEngine
    import org.papervision3d.typography.Font3D
    import org.papervision3d.typography.fonts.HelveticaBold
    import org.papervision3d.typography.Text3D
    import org.papervision3d.materials.special.Letter3DMaterial
    import flash.text.engine.FontDescription
    import flash.text.engine.ElementFormat
    import flash.text.engine.TextElement
    import flash.text.engine.TextBlock
    import flash.text.engine.TextLine

    /* @author vahid */
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var fd:FontDescription
        private var ef:ElementFormat
        private var te:TextElement        
        protected var st:String;

        private var scene:Scene3D
        private var view:Viewport3D
        private var camera:Camera3D
        private var render:BasicRenderEngine
        private var vpWidth:Number = stage.stageWidth;
        private var vpHeight:Number = stage.stageHeight;
        private var text3d:Text3D 
        private var font3d:Font3D 
        //private var font:HelveticaBold
        private var textMaterial:Letter3DMaterial 
        private var text:String 

        public function Main():void {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // rtl block 
            fd = new FontDescription ()                    
            ef = new ElementFormat (fd)            
            te = new TextElement ("?????? ?????? ???? ?????? ?? papervision", ef)

            text = te.text        
            //3d block

            scene = new Scene3D ()
            view = new Viewport3D (vpWidth,vpHeight,true,true,false,false)
            camera = new Camera3D ()
            render = new BasicRenderEngine()
            addChild (view)
            this.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME , renderThis)
            textMaterial = new Letter3DMaterial(0xFF0000,1)
            font3d = new HelveticaBold()
            text3d = new Text3D (text, font3d, textMaterial)
            scene.addChild (text3d)
        }

        protected function renderThis(e:Event):void 
        {
            text3d.rotationY +=5
            render.renderScene(scene,camera,view)
        }
    }
}
```

In case it is pertinent: I am using FlashDevelop.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue, or how I can get around it?

Comment: Does the last } belong to the code? I assume it is, to close package {

Answer (score 1):

I reckon helvetica-bold doesn't unfortunately contain the unicode characters you're trying to show. Just stumbled on [this post](http://www.nabble.com/TrueType-Parser-%2B-Font3D-%3D-Runtime-Font-Loading-td21191496.html), haven't checked it in depth but the idea seems interesting in case there is no arabic Font3D extension ...